# Xpath Upload Pic Avatar Twitter

Tags: python-3.x

Hello everyone I use python, and use selenium webdriver library to create software to upload pic avatar for newly registered Twitter account. But I can't use find_element_by_xpath to find the point. Can anyone help me?

```
upanh = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='css-901oao r-1awozwy r-jwli3a r-6koalj r-18u37iz r-16y2uox r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 r-b88u0q r-1777fci r-rjixqe r-dnmrzs r-bcqeeo r-q4m81j r-qvutc0']")
upanh.send_keys("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\Code\\1.png")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSXyv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Finding the tag by input type appears to currently work.

```
xpath="//input[@type='file']"
upanh = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,xpath)
upanh.send_keys("C:/mypic.jpg")
```